Volatility forecast, GARCH and/or HAR?
I am comparing 2 different sentiment datasets in predicting volatility, I would have 2 questions regarding this.
1, Does it make sense to use both GARCH and HAR models for this research to cover a wider scope?
2, For the HAR model I use intraday-minute level- data, for minutes that fall in the trading day, so 9:30-16:00.
My sentiment values are 24/7.
How can I handle sentiment values outside trading hours and weekends in the model? Would an exponential decay make sense for these timeframes?
Appreciate all the replies!

There isn't a technical "best" solution for this problem and this very much comes down to preference, situation and data available. But what I would do is treat how you are treating the overnight observation (the jumpy) the same for the realized-garch/HAR model, but use the net sentiment of the overnight period as 1-observation, then add a filter for the overnight period. This way the overnight returns observation is the lag of the sentiment. I am not sure what you mean by exponential decay, but the reduce overnight move would already be calibrated into the model without needing a decay funct.

Thank you very much! I will try that. And do you think there is 'merit' in using both GARCHA and HAR for the analysis? @THATSMYQUANTMYQUANTITATIVE

It's completely contextual - unfortunately risk-management is like this. But in my experience from work and in addition to lots on papers on this; GARCH(1,1) model works well. The more parameters added gives more unrealistic results (over-fitting). I would only start to add parameters or extra logic when I have a VERY good reason to do so: the relationship is very clear and there is a robust way to implement that relationship quantitatively.

Thats true, GARCH(1,1) has a decent performance, I guess it also uses shorter term volatility in the lags compared to HAR (conditional vol and realised vol) so I will use use both models. Thank you for the help @THATSMYQUANTMYQUANTITATIVE
